# How can I calculate the variance?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, variance

how can I calculate the variance with iterator?

```
public static double variance(final Iterator<Integer> array) {

}
```

-this method calculate the average

```
 private static double mean(final List<Integer> array) {
        return array.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(Double.NaN);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple statistics - Java packages for calculating mean, standard deviation, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735870/simple-statistics-java-packages-for-calculating-mean-standard-deviation-etc)

Comment: What is in the way of using the definition of variance? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: To calculate the variance without first writing everything to a list, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988556/11733759) you can do:

```java
public static double variance(final Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
  List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
  iterator.forEachRemaining(array::add);
  double mean = mean(array);
  double temp = 0;
  for(double a :array)
    temp += (a-mean)*(a-mean);
  return temp/(array.size()-1);
}
```

But it is strange that in `mean` is used `List`. If this `Iterator` is not needed than it can be:

```java
public static double variance(final List<Integer> array) {
  double mean = mean(array);
  double temp = 0;
  for(double a :array)
    temp += (a-mean)*(a-mean);
  return temp/(array.size()-1);
}
```

And with `stream`

```java
public static double variance(final Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
  List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
  iterator.forEachRemaining(array::add);
  double mean = mean(array);

  return array.stream()
          .map(a -> (a-mean)*(a-mean))
          .reduce(0d, Double::sum)/(array.size()-1);

}
```